# Do attacks of opportunity count as attack actions for the wording of Kinetic Blade?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, opportunity-attack, kineticist, occult-magic

The wording of Kinetic Blade is as follows:

> You form a weapon using your kinetic abilities. You create a nonreach, light or one-handed weapon in your hand formed of pure energy or elemental matter. (If you're a telekineticist, you instead transfer the power of your kinetic blast to any object held in one hand.) The kinetic blade's shape is purely cosmetic and doesn't affect the damage dice, critical threat range, or critical multiplier of the kinetic blade, nor does it grant the kinetic blade any weapon special features. The object held by a telekineticist for this form infusion doesn't prevent her from using gather power.
>
> You can use this form infusion once as part of an attack action, a charge action, or a full-attack action in order to make melee attacks with your kinetic blade. Since it's part of another action (and isn't an action itself), using this wild talent doesn't provoke any additional attacks of opportunity. The kinetic blade deals your kinetic blast damage on each hit (applying any modifiers to your kinetic blast's damage as normal, but not your Strength modifier). The blade disappears at the end of your turn. The weapon deals the same damage type that your kinetic blast deals, and it interacts with Armor Class and spell resistance as normal for a blast of its type. Even if a telekineticist uses this power on a magic weapon or another unusual object, the attack doesn't use any of the magic weapon's bonuses or effects and simply deals the telekineticist's blast damage. The kinetic blade doesn't add the damage bonus from elemental overflow.

Obviously, a normal kinetic blast is a standard action, and you wouldn't be able to use one as an AoO. But, given the way Kinetic Blade is worded, I'm wondering if it could be used in an attack of opportunity?

As an additional question, is it possible to threaten with one weapon, and use another? If I held a dagger in my off hand, could I then attack with the kinetic blade once the AoO was provoked?

Comment: [Same answer, different question.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/82902/8610) Also, I suggest asking your "additional question" as a separate question; it's an interesting one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, you cannot use Kinetic Blade during an Attack of Opportunity.**

It specifically spells out:

> an attack action, a charge action, or a full-attack action

An attack action is a specific type of action (from the PFSRD: [Combat (Standard Action)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#Table-Actions-in-Combat)):

> Attack Action: An attack action is a type of standard action. Some combat options can modify only this specific sort of action. When taking an attack action, you can apply all appropriate options that modify an attack action.

Whereas an attack of opportunity is not. While it is difficult to prove a negative (from the PFSRD: [Combat (Attacks of Opportunity)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Attacks-of-Opportunity)):

> These free attacks are called attacks of opportunity.

and

> An attack of opportunity is a single melee attack, and most characters can only make one per round.

seem to imply that an attack of opportunity are not attack actions as they are not mentioned in the attack action section nor called out as actions in their own section; they are instead considered 'free.'

Comment: Thank you. This is what I needed. The "an attack action is a type of standard action" is what sealed it for me. Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind that when the text does not say attack action, but simply attack or melee attack or ranged attack, it can be used of attacks of opportunity and iterative attacks.

Answer (score -5):

Correction, AoO would be possible as it defines it can be used for any attack action, they just over explain this. However most AoO occur after your turn ends and the ability directly says it disappears at the end of your turn. Seems many are confused on the word "Action". Heres a link to the definition of the word action which  a free attack falls under, since you have to do something to hit something: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/action

Comment: Using a dictionary entry to try to deny the limitations of terms of art that are specifically defined for game rules is just not cricket. "Action" in d20 games *does not* mean exactly the same as the usual dictionary definition, any more than "class" does.

Comment: "Attack Action: An attack action is a type of standard action." An Attack of Opportunity is **neither** "a standard action" **nor** a "free Attack Action" but a "free attack". ergo: it is not a valid target.

Comment: It seems this is a little late, but welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. I'm sorry that your first experience with the site has been to have this answer downvoted, but an RPG often uses words in different ways than the dictionary does, so most won't find useful the claim that a dictionary's definition overrides a game's term. However, if you can marshal more support for your position using the game's rules, this could become a useful answer. Anyway, have fun, thank you for participating, and and thank you for trying to help strangers.