# Can an Ally Across Time make opportunity attacks?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, opportunity-attack

[Ally Across Time](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/ally-across-time/) allows me to summon a copy of me, to help me with teamwork feats and such. But can my Ally make opportunity attacks?

> This duplicate has your statistics (though its hit points equal your caster level), threatens all squares adjacent to it, and has any teamwork feats you have.

Clearly it threatens an area, but...

> During its brief existence, a duplicate can use the aid another action once to assist you, but it cannot take any other type of action.

Well, that sounds very clear-cut at first. But... is an [Attack of Opportunity](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Attacks-of-Opportunity) an action? I've looked around a tiny bit and haven't found anything. If anyone has found a question that answers that, please link it or edit it in here. The closest I've found is [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89283/do-attacks-of-opportunity-count-as-attack-actions-for-the-wording-of-kinetic-bla).

So, my question is, **can my Ally Across Time make opportunity attacks?**

Comment: If so, then because the time duplicate "cannot use any of its equipment," Improved Unarmed Strike may be a necessity.

Comment: @HeyICanChan yeah, that's my next question - once I get an answer to this one. It's moot if the duplicate can't, but I am going to ask whether someone else can use the dupe's equipment. Also, why a necessity? Do we care if the dupe gets hit by an OA?

Comment: Because a creature doesn't normally threaten an area with an unarmed strike and the time duplicate can't use equipment yet the time duplicate threatens an area, the spell does make one wonder, "With what exactly *is* the time duplicate threatening that area?"

Comment: @HeyICanChan So many questions now. Like "If it had a spear of longness +15 ft, would it threaten those squares for teamwork feat purposes?" and "If it had an (imaginary) Medusa's Mask, would it petrify people who looked? What if it were a Medusa?" and "Why is noting that it threatens adjacent squares needed? For fairies that cast this spell?"

Comment: @HeyICanChan It's an ally across *time* - it comes from a different place of the caster's life. Therefore, I can only imagine it's a very old version of the character shouting "Get off my threatened area or I'll come over there" while shaking a first or a cane.

Comment: @VLAZ No, no, no, the ally cannot use a cane. It must be a fist.
Wow, that would explain everything about this spell. The duplicate can't move because he is old and weary and/or in a rocking chair, is too grumpy to do anything more than tell the PC what he's doing wrong (aid another), has only a tiny amount of hp because of all his ailments, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The spell says, in part

> This duplicate...threatens all squares adjacent to it...it cannot use any of its equipment...During its brief existence, a duplicate can use the aid another action once to assist you, but it cannot take any other type of action.

The way I read this, the duplicates all threaten only the squares around them (despite not being able to use any of their equipment, which includes weapons). Making an Attack of Opportunity is not an action, so the duplicate should be able to do so, despite the spell not saying either way explicitly. However, it would need to be an unarmed attack, since the duplicate can't use any equipment.

Comment: Which means that a Diminutive Fairy could use this spell to stab people at a "range"!

Comment: @Phoenices Assuming a fairy casts this spell, then yes. Similarly, with this spell, a Gargantuan caster's doubles only threaten the squares around them. That's what the spell says it does. If the spell was intended to use normal reach, then it would say so.

Comment: No, not necessarily. Does the spell ever say they do not threaten normally? An item that says "You may, as a standard action, threaten a square within 30 ft" would not invalidate the normal rules and make you not threaten adjacent squares. I think it still would work normally, though I'll ask a new question about it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Attack of Opportunity is an action.

There are six types of actions:[1](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Action-Types)

1. Standard
2. Move
3. Full-round
4. Swift
5. Immediate
6. Free

And Attack of Opportunity is a Free Action, so it is also an Action.  This is listed in the table [Combat Options Overview](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/Combat/#Table_Combat_Options_Overview).

Comment: Thank you! I never knew that - I don't think it says it anywhere else, but it definitely says it here. I'll wait a few hours, to see if someone can pull a counter-proof out of their hat.

Comment: Do you have a link to the Combat Options Overview table? I always thought that free actions (other than speaking) had to be taken on your turn and that AOOs were their own special thing.

Comment: @J-Pheeze You can search the answer's linked page for the Combat Options Overview. That table's from the *Melee Tactics Toolbox*, not the core rules, and, like many one-offs, there's no errata or clarifications because Paizo believed effort was wasted on fixing such texts. To be clear, if attacks of opportunity *are* free actions, then you're right, and they can't be taken off-turn, limiting substantially their usefulness. I'd take a harder line against this answer, but the game says what it says, even if it's nonsense. Still, making attacks of opportunity unique actions is better, long run.

Comment: I am unable to find anything saying an Attack of Opportunity is an action, free or otherwise. Can you provide a more specific supporting reference??

Comment: The closest I can find is in https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Attacks-of-Opportunity saying 'In this case, combatants near her can take advantage of her lapse in defense to attack her for free. These free attacks are called attacks of opportunity.' Free attack may not be the same as a free action.

Comment: Please provide a citation for Attacks of Opportunity being any kind of action. Because I don't think it is, and I'm downvoting for that.

Comment: The citation is in the answer. The Combat Options Overview table on the linked page.  I couldn't figure out how to get a link directly to that table, since its not listed in the table of contents, and manually building the # link with the table name didn't work either.

Comment: Found the non standard label in the page source, direct link added

Comment: It really does say that, though HeyICanChan points out how ridiculous it is. On the other hand, there is one other free action that can be done off-turn, and the attack of opportunity rules imply it can be done not on your turn. Still, given HeyICanChan's points, I won't accept this answer even though it may be correct, but you still have my upvote.

Comment: @GlenMartin given there is exactly one source saying an AoO is an action, and that source is a Player's Option book from fairly late in the print run, I'd be more inclined to think the one source is wrong, rather than take it as a precendent.